# fetch filepicker file into arraybuffer in web browser

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, arraybuffer, filepicker.io

I'm trying to use [filepicker.io](https://www.filepicker.io/) to fetch binary data and pass it into a function like this:

```
var doSomething = function(arrayBuffer) {
    var u16 = new Int16Array(arrayBuffer);
}
```

I have no idea how to convert the binary into arraybuffer like this:

```
filepicker.getContents(url, function(data){
//convert data into arraybuffer
}
```

I tried to follow [this tutorial on XMLHttpRequest](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/) but does't not work.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
    doSomething(this.response); 
};
```

Comment: XMLHttpRequest has nothing to do with reading file contents into a buffer. [This documentation may help you.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader)

Comment: You are not calling `.send` with your `XHR`

Comment: @Pointy https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data

Comment: @Esailija well yes but "fetch file picker file into array buffer" can be done whether or not anything's going to be posted back to a server.

Comment: @Pointy I am not familiar with the filepicker library but it seems he just needed to `.send` :P

Comment: Yes apparently - you must be a mind reader :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not calling `.send` with your `XHR`

```
xhr.send(null);
```